# If i pass an argument to my constructor, Do i want to pass argument for every time i am creating the object Instance?

Tags: php, oop

My class file is like below

```
<?php
class person { 
var $name; 

function __construct($persons_name) {   
    $this->name = $persons_name;    
}

function set_name($new_name) {
     $this->name = $new_name; 
} 

function get_name() { 
    return $this->name; 
} 
}
```

In my construct i am passing a value.
some where else when i want to create an instance of a object of person class like below

```
$hasee= new person(); 

$muja = new person("Mujahidh Haseem");
```

Do i want to pass a value strictly?
i am getting these notice for the first instance.

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for person::__construct(), called in D:\xampp\htdocs\oop\index.php on line 3 and defined in D:\xampp\htdocs\oop\class_lib.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: persons_name in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\oop\class_lib.php on line 6

Answer (score 2):

You can set default value for argument, which will be used, when argumet is omited

```
function __construct($persons_name = null) {
    if ($persons_name !== null)    
       $this->name = $persons_name;    
    else {
       // your code when argumet is omited
    }
}

$hasee= new person();
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL), expecting ')'`

Comment: how can i get the use of __constructor?

Comment: @mujas you can upvote both, but accept only one by your choice

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make the constructor argument optional, provide a default value.

```
function __construct($persons_name = null) {
    $this->name = $persons_name;
}
```

See PHP docs on [Default argument values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default).

If you don't want to make the argument optional, you'll have to provide it each time you are creating the instance or you'll get these errors.